# Can we use "requests" for non-game apps?

Tags: apprequests, facebook-app-requests, facebook-requests

I am unclear on whether Facebook requests (user to user) can only be used for Games Apps - or whether other web based FB Apps can use requests also.

We have a web based FB App - on our website a user can Connect with FB and start a fundraising campaign. We wish for the user to then be able to invite FB friends to view their campaign. But we are unclear how we can possibly communicate with our registered users FB friends. Can we use requests for this?

Any advice appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply wanting to invite users to your app, the [Requests Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) is the easiest way to do that:

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'My Great Request'
    }, yourCallbackFunction);
```